# Gaps in statistics of Java Melody

Tags: tomcat, grails, production

Currently I am facing issues, that the java melody statistics running for a grails application having some "gaps" (for **all** graphs at the same time!). I cannot see any issues from the logs and the server seems to be running fine within those gaps. The gaps seem to appear at any time, I cannot figure out any systematics.

[image: Example of a gap within the memory consumption graph]
[image: Example of a gap within the session statistics]

```
JDK: jdk1.6.0_25
Application server: Tomcat 6.0.33
OS: Debian 2.6.32-028stab094.3
Grails: 1.3.7
Grails Java Melody Plugin-version: 1.5
```

What can be the reason for this?

When does java melody stops recording values? Running out of threads, out of memory?

Comment: does your app has some heavy scheduled jobs?

Comment: one job running each minute using quartz (0.4.2). maximum execution time is at one second.

Comment: Are the gap times consistent? If so, whats the average duration?

Comment: No - for weeks its fine, but then some days its a often (like 10 gaps within 2 hours).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The server has ran out of open file handles and could not write statistics to disk.

Answer (score 0):

How large is your Heapsize ? (-Xmx). JVM pauses can often be related to garbage collection of the tenured generation.

Comment: These are my only customized options for the tomcat: CATALINA_OPTS="-Xmx768m  -XX:MaxPermSize=256m"

Comment: As your heap size is as small as 768 MB, the JVM wont pause for any significant amount of time. Network lag/dropped packaged betweent the application being monitored and Java Melody ? Otherwise, I dont have any good suggestions as I have never used JavaMelody myself.